# Prove the sum of a series converges iff limit of a sequence exists

Tags: sequences-and-series

The problem says

Let $\{b_n\}$ be a sequence and let $a_n=b_n - b_{n-1}$. Prove the following:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges if and only if $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n$exists.

I want to read up on this theorem, but I can't seem to find it anywhere on google. What is it called?

Comment: What is bn1?? Perhaps $\;b_{n-1}\;$ or $\;b_{n+1}\;$ ?

Comment: I don't think it has a name, it's too elementary for that. Just look at the definitions, and find what $$\sum_{n = 1}^k a_n$$ is. It is then immediate.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ = $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n - b_{n-1}$

$a_n$ = $b_n - b_0$

This will lead to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ = $b_n - b_0$ for all n

The two sequences differ by the constant $b_0$

If $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n$ converges then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ will converge.

I'm not sure how to write this more professionally (if it's right).

Comment: No. Start small. What is $a_1 + a_2$. Then, what is $a_1 + a_2 + a_3$? That should let you see what $\sum_{n = 1}^k a_n$ is for arbitrary $k$.

Comment: $a_1$ is $b_1 - b_0$  and 

$a_1 + a_2 + a_3$ is $-b_0 + b_3$

Comment: It's $b_3 - b_0$, not $b_0 + b_3$. Can you see what $\sum_{n = 1}^k a_n$ will be?

Comment: yeah sorry I keep trying to do a new line and hitting the comment. That will be $b_n - b_0$

Comment: $b_k - b_0$, $n$ is the running index, and $k$ the bound. So, can you see that $\sum a_n$ converges if and only if $(b_n)$ converges?

Comment: Oh yes my bad on the n instead of k. So $b_n$ will be the limit I can see that. $b_0$ however i'm not sure what that does. Say you had 2x/x. $b_n$ would be 2 and $b_0$ would be undefined. Do you plug zero in for $b_0$ or am I wrong in thinking that?

Comment: I don't understand your confusion. $b_0$ is given. It may be $0$, or it may be any other number. If we denote the partial sums of $\sum a_n$ by $s_k$, i.e. $s_k = \sum_{n = 1}^k a_n$, then we have $s_k = b_k - b_0$ for all $k$. The two sequences differ by a constant, and so one converges if and only if the other converges, and if they converge, the limits will differ by the same constant. So, assuming convergence, we have $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n = \lim_{k\to\infty} s_k = \lim_{k\to\infty} (b_k - b_0) = \left(\lim_{k\to\infty} b_k\right) - b_0.$$

Comment: if $b_n$ was 2x/x then $b_0$ would be undefined wouldn't it? If $b_0$ is given as a different number that makes sense to me. But if you plug it in like you do for any value up to k then won't you get undefined? I understand both of them differing by the same constant, but my issue is when that constant results in an undefined(once again if $b_0$ is given to not be undefined then there is no issue).

Comment: "If $b_n$ was $2x/x$" makes no sense. You probably meant $b_n = 2n/n$? Anyway, you're looking at it from a wrong point. It is immaterial _what_ $b_0$ (or more general $b_n$) is [that influences the value of the series - if convergent - of course, but not the behaviour, whether it is convergent or not]. All that matters is that $b_0$ **exists**. It must in some way or other be defined, otherwise $a_1$ isn't defined, and the statement makes no sense at all. It is part of the (implicit) hypotheses of the problem that $b_0$ exists.

Comment: Okay that makes more sense. $b_0$ must exist. I edited my answer but I still feel I am missing a step.